# Alternativas a Eclipse para desarrollar en J2EE

Tags: java, java-ee, ide

Hace tiempo que ando buscando una alternativa sólida a Eclipse para desarrollar sobre J2EE, ya que en ciertos momentos Eclipse se muestra un tanto "errático" (fallos, corrupción, ...) sobre todo cuando tratas de trabajar con un servidor J2EE como puede ser Wildfly.

Para ser más específico en cuanto a lo que requiero:

- Es necesario que soporte trabajar directamente con servidores J2EE (Wildfly)
- Que tenga soporte comercial, donde poder apoyarnos
- Permitir extensiones/plugins o al menos que nosotros podamos desarrollar dichas extensiones

¿Que IDE conocéis que cumpla estos puntos?

Comment: Estimado Taber, aunque incluso a mi me gustaría saber la respuesta, no es el tipo de preguntas aceptadas en la comunidad. Aunque ciertamente un IDE es una herramienta usada por los programadores, preguntar sobre alternativas es meramente subjetivo.

Comment: Hola Taber he usado Java e Intellij IDEA, pero te podría comentar que con Eclipse no he tenido problemas, tal vez el problema es el servidor Wildfly  que comentas =0.

Comment: * Perdón en lugar de Java quería decir Netbeans, y  pienso lo mismo que Paul, probablemente es problema de configuración.

Comment: Aunque indicas que buscas algo distinto, quizás te aconsejaría usar Eclipse con [JBoss Tools](http://tools.jboss.org/), puesto es algo que ya conoces. Con JBoss Tools tendrás una fácil integración con Wildfly, y si necesitases algún soporte comercial, tanto Jboss Tools como Wildfly son productos de Red Hat, por lo que podrías pagar por tener un soporte.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para el desarrollo con Java existen en el mercado varias alternativas :

### Netbeans

Es un IDE bastante bueno para el desarrollo de entornos gráficos con java, pero adicionalmente puedes desarrollar en otros lenguajes como PHP, Ruby, etc.

### JDeveloper

Mantenido con Oracle, posee una excelente integración con este motor de base de datos, monolenguaje, dispone de herramientas de análisis de código como diseño de diagramas ER, UML.

### IntelliJ IDEA

***De Pago***

Una excelente competencia para Netbeans, es un IDE multilenguaje, posee herramientas para mejora de productividad.

> *Android Studio esta basado en este Editor*

### JBuilder

Este IDE esta basado en eclipse, dispone de 3 ediciones:

- Enterprise (La mas completa, orientado al desarrollo sobre JEE)
- Professional
- Developer

Comment: Yo por mi parte, y por ampliar tu contestación he encontrado "myeclipse", pero no tengo ninguna referencia sobre dicha herramienta.

Answer (score 7):

Puedes usar [IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/#chooseYourEdition).

**Pro's:** cumple con todos los requisitos que pides, y la verdad es que trabajar con este IDE es una gozada, es **robusto**, tiene muy buena **integración** de plugins, esta casi todo lo necesario en la versión base y da infinidad de **ayudas** a la hora de producir **codigo** **limpio rápidamente**.

**Problema:** la version que soporta JavaEE es de pago y **solo tienes 30 dias de prueba gratuitos.**

Comment: uno de los criterios es que tenga soporte comercial, asi que creo que piensan pagar por ello por lo que para quien hace la pregunta el pagar no es un problema

Comment: Un detalle de la versión comercial de IntelliJ (que por otra parte la recomiendo encarecidamente), que si la adquieres de manera personal, el coste se reduce muchísimo, pero con la condición de que la empresa no reembolse el coste de la licencia. Puede ser una alternativa si la compra por parte de la empresa no es posible. Suerte!

Answer (score 6):

Una buen alternativa gratuita desde mi punto de vista es *Netbeans*, no te lías con los módulos porque ya tienes todo integrado, tienes buena documentación. A mi me facilita el trabajo. Ademas puedes descargar solo la versión que contiene Java EE.

Answer (score 0):

Como varios colegas indican en realidad hay muchos IDE`s para poder desarrollar no solo en J2EE si no que la mayoria de ellos se adapta para J2SE, sin embargo desde mi punto de vista eclipse es de los mejores IDE`s para el desarrollo de aplicaciones en Java ya que es demasiado completo y ayuda mucho al desarrollo ràpido de aplicaciones ahorrando el tiempo de desarrollo, ya que si lo comparamos con otros IDE`s por ejemplo NetBeans este utiliza demasiados recursos de las maquinas y si lo comparamos con otros como JCreator o IntellingenJ el desarrollo de aplicaciones es muy costo hablando en cuanto a tiempos.
Estoy muy de acuerdo en que en muchas ocasiones eclipse se traba o manda varios errores sin embargo a mi me ha funcionado bastante cerrarlo y abrirlo nuevamente. 
Espero mi comentario haya sido de aporte.
Puedo recomendar estos cursos de java http://www.grupocodesi.com/cursos/curso-de-java-basico.html